# How to make puppeteer headless mode as fast as possible?

Tags: puppeteer

I just wanted to know, what the common ways are, to make Puppeteer in headless mode even faster.
In other words, is it possible to reduce the loading times of websites in puppeteer?

Comment: Do you have an actual use case? There are a million ways to make things run faster but not all apply to all cases. For example, you could block images, but maybe your use case is to screenshot the images, in which case that technique wouldn't help. Speculating and making lists of techniques is off-topic -- SO works best when there's an immediate, concrete problem to be solved, otherwise, there's no real concrete answer, just lists of opinions and guesswork.

Comment: Hey, sorry You're right. In my case, Puppeteer should just load up a website, click some buttons, then it should get redirected to a new page and click some buttons again and it should do the whole thing as fast as possible

Comment: OK, thanks. Could you share the website and the code you're using? Every site is different, so for example, if you can click all the buttons using different pages, you can parallelize the operation. But if the buttons are in sequential form, that won't work, so the request is still pretty speculative here.